# initialize an array from another array in C

Tags: c

I would like to initialise an array with the value set in another array, like:

```
uint8_t array_1[] = {1, 2, 3};

uint8_t array_2[] = array_1;
```

Of course this would not work since array_1 is considered a pointer. What I'm trying to do is to be able to statically initialize `array_2` with the value of `array_1` without using `memset`.

Since array_1 and array_2 would in my case be constant global buffers, I believe there should be a way to do this, but I haven't figured out how, or by using defines, but I'd rather stick to the other solution if possible.

Thank you

Comment: Generally you make an explicit copy.

Comment: how would you do that in C ?

Comment: If they are really both going to be constant global buffers, then maybe you don't actually need two of them. `uint8_t* array_2 = array_1;`

Comment: `#define INITIAL_VALUES {1, 2, 3}`

Comment: @pmg or an include file

Comment: You can't use `memset` to copy values from one array to another. This is what `memcpy` is for  - of course, it is not static initialization.

Comment: @SergeyA he probably meant `memcpy`.

Comment: @tim-randall they'll probably remain constant, but in my case, I need a memory copy of the array since I need to put it in a struct with other values, and then do the hash of the struct. Having a hash of a pointer would not work.

Comment: Yes `memcpy` is what I've meant, my bad

Comment: @kokopelli you can [edit] your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no particularly elegant way to do this at compile-time in C than using `#define` or repeating the initializer. The simplest versions:

```
uint8_t array_1[] = {1, 2, 3};
uint8_t array_2[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

or

```
#define INIT_LIST {1, 2, 3}

uint8_t array_1[] = INIT_LIST;
uint8_t array_2[] = INIT_LIST;
```

Though if you were using structs, you could do:

```
typedef struct
{
  int arr [3];
} array_t;

array_t array_1 = { .arr = {1,2,3} };
array_t array_2 = array_1;
```

But that only works if these are local objects and this is essentially equivalent to calling `memcpy`.

Comment: Wouldn't just `array_t array_1 = { 1, 2, 3 };` work, or is that using some nasty Microsoft extension? (It *does* work on MSVC and clang-cl.)

Comment: @AdrianMole Yeah that works thanks to C's complex and kind of dysfunctional rules of initialization of "sub-objects", but gcc will generate a warning if you do. Alternatively you could also do `array_t array_1 = { {1,2,3} };`. I think designated initializers is the most readable form.

Comment: Sometimes, "dysfunctional" is nice! If only there were a way to use compound literals as typedefs and then use those to initialize arrays...

Comment: @AdrianMole Not so nice if you have `typedef struct { int arr [3]; int x; } array_t;` and then `array_t array_1 = { 1,2,3 };`. Now did I leave out the initialization of x on purpose (set to zero), or did I forget it?

Answer (score -3):

You can do it like this

```
uint8_t length = sizeof(array_1) / sizeof(array_1[0]);
for(uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  array_2[i] = array_2[i]
}
```

Comment: hey @codingwith3dv, since it's statically allocated in my case, I do not have acces to any function. Furthermore I'm working in C, not C++, so no vectors available.

Comment: Where did you allocate memory for array_2? (your 1st solution)

Comment: @codingwith3dv your new answer is somewhat better, but still wrong. He want's to do the initialisation _statically_.